# Unknow source of daily clean up of indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have two separate elastic clusters, each one of elastic node is docker container, which live in docker swarm. I aggregate logs from various microservices in indices, and one of them is in format "*logs-timestamp"*.

In one of cluster I have those indices from previous days, in other one I have only from present day.
This affect only those ones in *"logs-timestamp"* format.

Do you have any idea? or point from I can start to lookup?
Does elastic has some form of builtin garbage collector?

Ps. I didn't start this project so basiclly I have quite small knowledge about whole infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the ILM policies documentation ([here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/getting-started-index-lifecycle-management.html)) which is one way of automatically removing old indices.

In short, check the result of this command in kibana

```
GET _ilm/policy
```

It will tell you if you have some policy configured.

The other way I know for automatic indices curation is Curator ( see [here](https://postmarkapp.com/blog/tools-we-use-curator-for-elasticsearch) and [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/index.html)). You should check if Curator is installed somewhere in your infrastructure and check the configuration.

Hope it helps.

Comment: So I try this request against both of clusters, but both of them equally give me "No endpoint or operation is available at [policy]" so I think I don't have such policy configured, I am trying to find where this curator is placed but this is also other kind of problems.